# Word did not save the document

Tags: microsoft-word, windows-8.1, onedrive

I receive an error if I create a new document in Microsoft Word 2013 and then try to save it to OneDrive. How do I avoid that error message and actually save?

**Here are the steps to reproduce:**

1. Open MS Word 2013.
2. Create a new blank document by clicking "Blank Document"
3. After the document opens, choose File > Save.
4. Choose OneDrive - Personal , then click Browse.
5. Name the document, then click Save.
6. The error will say "Word did not save the document."

**This is my save screen:**

[image: Saving to OneDrive]

**This is the error message:**

[image: Word did not save the document]

My current workaround is to save to the Desktop, and then to drag the document into OneDrive. Is there a way to save directly to OneDrive?

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR; Replace the Save As address with "OneDrive" and press enter!** You can then save to anywhere in OneDrive.

**Details**

How do I avoid that error message and actually save?

1. Open MS Word 2013.
2. Create a new blank document by clicking "Blank Document"
3. After the document opens, choose File > Save.
4. Choose OneDrive - Personal , then click Browse.

At this point, you will that the address bar contains this or something like it:

> Web Sites > https://d.docs.live.net > db5db99f78f6191

[image]

If you click on that, it will change to this address:

> https://d.docs.live.net/db5db99f7f8f6191

[image]

**Replace that text with "OneDrive" and press enter.**

[image]

You can now save directly to OneDrive from Word.